# Access dynamic id in template in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor template that has a selector id="{{_id}}". It gets the current teacher name object and assigns the id value of that teacher to the id of the selector. There's more than one selector per teacher, but this is one example:

```
<template name="oneTeacher">
  {{#each TeacherNames}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <select id="{{_id}}">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Week</option>
        <option value="Week1">Week 1</option>
        ...
```

How can I get that id value inside a change function with a Meteor event? It would need to be something like:

```
Template.oneTeacher.events({
  'change #this._id': function () { // doesn't work
    console.log('changed');
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `id`. Add a `class` to the element that you want to target and use `this._id` in the event handler. It will hold the data context (the `TeacherName` in your case).

Comment: Apologies for the dumb question, but how would I access the value of the changed selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your field something that can be used as a selector, such as a `class` attribute.

```html
<template name="oneTeacher">
  {{#each TeacherNames}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <select class="week-select">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Week</option>
        <option value="Week1">Week 1</option>
```

since it is within an `#each` clause, it will be bound to the relevant array element's value.

```js
Template.oneTeacher.events({
  'change .week-select'(e, tpl) {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

The value of `this` will be the respective `TeacherNames` entry.

Comment: Correct, as written in the answer. If you want the `select` node, you can use `e.target`.